# Material ui icons

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

**Problem description**

I have a react-django app with material-ui. I used to import and *material-ui icons* without any problem. Today, I couldn't even build my app after importing a new icon from **material-ui**.

> import WebIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Web';

This is the error message when I try to start my react app,

```
> react-scripts start
Starting the development server...
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@mui/icons-material/utils/createSvgIcon.js
 Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/material/utils' in 
'/home/ztaye/Documents/Work/Afropa/code/afropa/frontend/node_modules/@mui/icons- 
material/utils'
/home/ztaye/Documents/Work/Afropa/code/afropa/frontend/node_modules/react- 
scripts/scripts/start.js:19
throw err;
^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/initrd.img'
```

**Expectation**

I just suspect the error is coming from their new updates. I have tried to re-install the package using this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/icons-material), it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's backward compatibility issue after an update from *material-ui*. It started to work after I replace all

```
@mui/icons-material/
```

to

```
@material-ui/icons/
```

On each icon imports.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know Django but in my React i import:
import ArrowForwardIosIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowForwardIos';

if you install it like this: npm i @material-ui/icons

Comment: As I have explained before, I installed it on such a way